# Inserting points into a polygon

Tags: algorithms, polygons

I want to insert $n$ points into arbitrary polygon $P$ described by ordered list of its vertexes $v_1, v_2, ..., v_m$. Each inserted point must distanced from the others on distance at least $d$. In case when $n$ it to large to do it, we should be able to detect such situation.

Here is example solution for $n=8$ (green circle diameter is equal to some $d$).

[image]

I try to find something about this problem on internet but no luck. So also I try myself to figure out how to do it - my idea was to split polygon into convex parts and put points on each part but there is problem to set proper distance between points in two parts (and putting points into convex part is also not trivial for me). Any idea?

Comment: Instead of the polygon $P$, consider the set $P+B$ which is the set of points $p + b$ where $p \in P$ and $b$ is in the disk $B$ radius $R$.  This set looks like a fatter version of $P$, but with rounded corners.  Your problem then is to pack circles into this set, so search for "circle packing".  Except for some special shapes, general solutions are hard to find, but there are numerical approaches possible.

Comment: @J.J.Green But there can be balls contained in P+B with center outside P

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín : I think you're quite right, a simple example is $P$ the unit square (not its interior) and the ball $B$ radius $R = \sqrt 2 / 2$, then the centre of the square is in $P+B$, the ball radius $R$ centred there is in $P+B$ ... so please ignore the above.

Comment: A collection of vertices doesn't determine a polygon. You need more information. For example, consider four vertices with one in the convex hull of the other three. Also, I doubt you want the number of points to insert to equal the number of vertices.

Comment: A decent strategy is probably to build an energy functional incorporating "hard core" point-point interaction terms with radius $d$ and a hard core point-edge interaction term with radius zero. Then use your favorite optimization technique.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman - of course, on input we have an ordered list of vertices -  I thought that this is obvious

Comment: Please state the problem more precisely. Your example shows that you probably do not wish to obtain  the same number $n$ of interior points as the number of vertices. So you should define $P$ by a tuple $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m)$, where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ . Also it is not clear if the problem is to find any arrangement, or if you try to find the maximal number $n$ of interior points separated by distances $\geq d$. One approach is to find a maximal  intersection of the hexagonal lattice spanned by $(d, d\,e^{i\,\pi/3})$ in the complex plane with a rotated and translated copy of $P$.

Comment: I suggest the centers of the disks should lie on the medial axis of , a.k.a. the cut locus. E.g., see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31832/6094). This could reduce the search to locating those centers on a tree inside .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy greedy algorithm for this, circle packing is a hard problem and most results are about simple instances e.g. circle packing in a [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle), [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square), [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_an_equilateral_triangle) and it is one of the problems in the book ["Unsolved problems in geometry](https://archive.org/details/unsolvedproblems0000crof/page/108/mode/2up)

there is an upperbound on $n$ of $\lfloor{\frac{A + Pd}{\pi d^2}}\rfloor ​+ 1$  where $A, P$ are the area and perimetar of the polygon, which can be proved easily for the case of convex polygons, but that upperbound is not always possible

I suggest to try to use randomized algorithms, I also do think that genetic algorithms can get great results for this problem

Comment: Good point - however I'm not sure that this is circle packing problem - because circles can cross Poly borders

Comment: it's, at least for convex polygon because if we extend the walls of the polygon outwards distance d then the answer of the circle backing for this new polygon works for the original problem as well